# I want to send user to another page after login (node js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code that checks  if a user exists in a database or not . 
After checking,if it is successfully i want to send the user to another page (html page) , else i want to redirect the page.

But with this code , if the user exists or not i always have "no exist "at the console and redirect to the same page

this is my code :

```js
require('./models/medecinmodel')
require('./models/infirmiermodel')
require('./models/patientmodel')
var medecin= require('./models/medecinmodel')
var infirmier= require('./models/infirmiermodel')
var patient= require('./models/patientmodel')
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
//Import the mongoose module
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var path=require('path');
//Set up detfault mongoose connection
var mongoDb = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb1' ;
mongoose.connect(mongoDb) ;
//Get Mongoose to use the global promise library

mongoose.Promise= global.Promise ;
// Get the default connection
var db =mongoose.connection ;

//bind connection to error event ( to get notification of connection errors
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console , 'mongoDb connection error:'));


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.listen(3000,function () {
    console.log("okkkk")
})


app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html");
})



app.post('/login',function (req,res) {
    
    medecin.find( {pseudo: req.query.pseudo, mdp: req.query.mdp}, function (err, docs) {
        if (docs.length !== 0) {
            console.log("user exists");
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/adddoctor.html");
        }
        else {
            console.log("no exist");
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is seems like a bad practice.. try to use any of the template engine instead of a direct html file.. Ex: `embedded js` https://ejs.co/

Comment: i solved the problem by changing the code this way :app.get('/login',function (req,res) {
    
    medecin.findOne( {pseudo: req.query.pseudo, mdp: req.query.mdp}) 
        
    .exec(function (err, result) {
        if(result) { 
           res.sendFile(__dirname + "/adddoctor.html"); 
           

        }

        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html");
       
          
       
       
        
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by changing the code this way :

app.get('/login',function (req,res) {

```
medecin.findOne( {pseudo: req.query.pseudo, mdp: req.query.mdp}) 

.exec(function (err, result) {
    if(result) { 
       res.sendFile(__dirname + "/adddoctor.html"); 


    }

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html");





});
```

});